# mvc4, trouble with WebMatrix reference and Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have a maddening situation here with an `MVC4` site. At the outset, you need to know it uses Windows authentication, and I also want to use `simplemembership` roles (but I don't think this is working--but this is not the focus of my question). Basically, the site works on my `dev` machine (with `IIS` Express) and a test machine (with regular `IIS`). But it doesn't work in production environment. We get an error "could not load file or assembly `WebMatrix.WebData, version=2.0.0.0`.

The `WebMatrix.WebData` reference has `CopyLocal = False`. (This works in `dev` and `test`.) If I set `CopyLocal = True`, then the authentication goes haywire. Specifically, when you visit the site, it attempts a redirect to `login.aspx` (obviously not an `MVC` component). So, my question is Why is this happening? How do I fix?

Here's what I've got under my system.web element in the config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

I've played around with this quite a bit trying to understand the problem, but I don't really know what I'm doing with this config section/what all can be done. I wonder if there's a problem clearing all the membership providers.... while trying to use the `SimpleRoleProvider`. (I tried cutting out `SimpleRoleProvider`, but this had no effect on problem.)

Comment: btw, the reason I have a WebMatrix reference at all is so I can get the current user name without being inside a controller. (WebSecurity.CurrentUserName works outside of a controller.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049926/asp-net-4-5-custom-membership-provider-configuration-throws-strange-exception