# This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage when using IIS7.5 but not local IIS Web Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have inherited an app....

When I try to run it locally it works great when I use Local IIS Web Server IIS Express. :

```
"http://localhost:port/"
```

When I try to use IIS7.5 I get the below stated error. :

This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage

I have seen these posts but none of them have helped. :

[ASP.NET: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626647/asp-net-this-method-cannot-be-called-during-the-applications-pre-start-initial)

[asp.net 4.5 custom membership provider configuration throws strange exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049926/asp-net-4-5-custom-membership-provider-configuration-throws-strange-exception)

I already have these in my web.config. :

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
```

And I have checked for these in my bin folders and they are not to be found. :

WebMatrix.WebData.dll and WebMatrix.Data.dll

Confused at the moment as the developer of this fairly large application is no longer available to contact.  So attempting to figure out how to run this application locally but have been stuck at this point for quite some time.

Comment: What application? any idea what method? Have you tried decompiling it with something like Reflector?

Comment: It blows up in the webconfig.  Like I said above it works in local iis express but not via iis 7.5.

Comment: Did you find any solution?